# How to avoid disappointing my friend when I criticize her writing?

Tags: compliments

Recently, a close friend of mine has started writing very short novels. From a conversation we had, I could clearly tell that she is very proud of the fruit of her labor and seriously considers writing professionally.

I accepted to provide feedback, which she has been eager to receive. I now regret this decision, for I find myself unable to formulate a single compliment about the first two samples she sent me. To be blunt: she hasn't proof-read herself and it shows.

Time pressure is piling up too, as she has sent me a third short and specifically asked for my opinion about the two previous writings, clearly expecting praise.

I can foresee that she would be deeply hurt by strongly negative critics, especially given how highly she regards her own work. Nonetheless, I want to remain as honest as possible.

**How can I give my friend the feedback she demands while not hurting her feelings nor being dishonest?**

Comment: I have to add that I haven't responded to either of her messages yet.

Comment: Hi Alexis and welcome to the site! We have a couple past questions about giving feedback to friends on their creative works - do either of these help you? [How can I tell a friend that their self-published book needs editing?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/12255) (more about needing proofreading) or [How to tell my friend his novel's ending is too predictable but he should keep writing it?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/10846) (more about the content).

Comment: So to get you correct: Your question doesn't focus on giving her feedback, but explicitly asks for helping her to improve? So an answer ignoring the feedback problem would totally serve your purpose? The title isn't matching that, tho. Maybe you should change the title if I got you correct.

Comment: @EmC How did I miss those! The second question and its answers are exactly what I need, thanks!

Comment: @dhein No, she specifically asked for feedback, sorry that the boldface question makes this unclear. I'm not editing because I expect this will be closed as duplicate

Comment: @Alexis: Even then it might be still a good idea to either change the title, or the bottom line question, so future readers, can feel more certain about the marked duplicate leading to what they are looking for. :)

Comment: Hey Alexis! I've marked your question as a duplicate, so we can keep answers in one place. It will also make a good signpost, a place for people other people to find the other question. If at any point you start struggling with any of the answers, or get stuck, feel free to ask a new question to point out how the answers there didn't answer your question :)